# Javascript methods from super class

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, so some of the existing answers on StackOverflow confused me.

If I have a static class inside of a dynamic class (like below).  How can I access variables inside the dynamic class?

```
function ListItem() = {
  var myItem = function() { return "something" };

  ...
  ItemDropdown = function(){
     show : function (){
       //Want to access the ListItem's myItem here
       alert(super.myItem() + "dropdown menu");
     }
  }
}


var foo = new ListItem();
foo.ItemDropdown.show();
```

Comment: your formatting has syntax errors, like function x() = {

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes. At least, not in the same sense that, say, Java does. You may like to read [what MDN has to say on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages). Note also that `this` in JavaScript works very differently to Java or C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `ItemDropdown` to be a method of `ListItem`, you need to declare it using `this`.

```
this.ItemDropdown = {
```

With the way you have `myItem` defined, you can just call it by itself.

```
alert(myItem() + "dropdown menu");
```

You also have a couple syntax errors:

```
function ListItem() = {
// Should be
function ListItem() {
```

and

```
ItemDropdown = function(){
// Should be
this.ItemDropdown = {
```

So, you end up with this:

```
function ListItem() {
  var myItem = function() { return "something" };

  this.ItemDropdown = {
     show : function (){
       alert(myItem() + "dropdown menu");
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Javascript is not class based inheritance, it is prototype based inheritance. You need to use terms such as "function constructor". If you are coming from a "traditional" class based inheritance language, then check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) out.

This being said, if you want this to work:

```
var foo = new ListItem();
foo.ItemDropdown.show();
```

Then `ItemDropdown` must be a property of the `ListItem` definition (eg: function constructor) - which means you need to use `this`.

Answer (score 0):

use `this`

```
function ListItem()  {
  var myItem = function() { return "something" };

  ...
  this.ItemDropdown = {
     show : function (){
       //Want to access the ListItem's myItem here
       alert(myItem() + "dropdown menu"); // no super in javascript
     }
  }
}
```

I've fixed to errors:

1. ) ListItem() = {
2. ) this.ItemDropdown = function () { // then object literal mark up